# How to get the Oracle database object type using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle.manageddataaccess

I have a block of code with the logic of getting a type from an Oracle database using the **Devart.Data.Oracle** package:

```cs
using Devart.Data.Oracle;
...
using (var c = new OracleConnection(connectionString)
{
    await c.OpenAsync();
    OracleType myType = OracleType.GetObjectType("SCHEMA.TYPE_NAME", connectionString);
    c.Close();
}
```

But I need to implement the same logic of getting the type using the **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess** package, but this package does not support the `OracleType` class and the `GetObjectType()` method

I tried to use the `OracleUdt` class, but it does not contain a method for getting a type from an Oracle database. Maybe I should use the `OracleCustomTypeMapping` class?